# OSError at /app/ Why does such a strange error happen?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I got an error:

> OSError at /app/
>
> [Errno 63] File name too long: "/Users/xxx/testapp/templates/jinja2/{'items': [{'---': '---', ‘A’: ‘a’, ‘B’: ‘b’, ‘C: ‘c’, ‘D’: ‘d’}]}

I wanna embed `json_dict` of json_parse method's result in `views.py` to `index.html`. I wrote in `views.py` like

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

def index(request):
    f = open('./data/data.json', 'r')
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    return render('./index.html',json_dict)
```

I wrote in index.html like

```
<html>
　<head>
　<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
　<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.css">
　</head>
　<body>
    <select id="mainDD" data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:600px;">
    {% for k, v in json_dict.items %}
            <option>{{ v }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

`json_dict` has dictionary of `{'items': [{'---': '---' ~~~` .I really cannot understand why I cannot send `json_dict` to `index.html`. Am I wrong to use render method? How can I fix this?

urls.py of app(child app) has views.py&index.html is

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

urls.py of parent app is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
]
```

Traceback is

```
Traceback:

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/testapp/app/views.py" in index
  8.     return render('./index.html',json_dict)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  21.             return engine.get_template(template_name)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in get_template
  39.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in get_template
  162.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template
  136.                         name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py" in get_template
  38.                 contents = self.get_contents(origin)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loaders/filesystem.py" in get_contents
  28.             with io.open(origin.name, encoding=self.engine.file_charset) as fp:

Exception Type: OSError at /app/
Exception Value: [Errno 63] File name too long: "/Users/xxx/testapp/templates/jinja2/{'items': [{'---': '---', ‘A’: ‘a’, ‘B’: ‘b’, ‘C: ‘c’, ‘D’: ‘d’}]}
```

After editing by an answer,I got an error TypeError at /app/
**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'match_extension' .
Traceback says
Traceback:

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in **getitem**
65.             return self._engines[alias]

During handling of the above exception ('django'), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/xxx/testapp/app/views.py" in index
13.     return render(request, 'jinja2/index.html', {'json_dict': json_dict})

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
67.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
18.     engines = _engine_list(using)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in _engine_list
72.     return engines.all() if using is None else [engines[using]]

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in all
89.         return [self[alias] for alias in self]

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in 
89.         return [self[alias] for alias in self]

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/utils.py" in **getitem**
80.             engine = engine_cls(params)

File "/Users/xxx/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in **init**
32.         self.engine = Engine(self.dirs, self.app_dirs, **options)

Exception Type: TypeError at /app/
Exception Value: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'match_extension'

Comment: With render all is ok. Error says that your filename in `templates/jinja2/...` is to long. Check it and rename.

Comment: @Vladyslav My json file's name is "data.json".I do not think this file name is too wrong.I think other points is wrong.

Comment: add your urls.py file. Maybe mistakes in it, because in views and templates all Ok. And add your file tree for `templates/jinja2` direcrory with all filenames

Comment: This isn't the code that gives that error. Please show the actual code and the full traceback.

Comment: @Vladyslav I added urls.py.if u know something please help me

Comment: your call to render() is wrong.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added full traceback.if u know something please help me

Comment: @Loïc I cannot understand what u r saying.Could u write codes in answer or comment?

Comment: Can you please start using proper words. "u r" is not how to communicate.

Comment: Aloso you now need to show your templates settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `render()` is wrong, try this :

```
def index(request):
    with open('./data/data.json', 'r') as f:
        json_dict = json.loads(f.read())
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'json_dict': json_dict})
```

Everything is in the doc :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render

Comment: Probably shouldn't be using `./` in the path; templates are relative to the template dir settings.

Comment: thx ur answer.I tried ur codes, but firstly I got error TypeError: JSON object must be str, not TextIOWrapper.So I changed ` json.loads(f)` into `json.load(f)`,but next I got an error No module named 'match_extension' .What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I tried ur new codes, but TypeError at /app/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'match_extension' error happens.What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I think it's because your template directory contains a `jinja2` folder. Either move index.html to its parent folder (`templates`), or edit your `render()` call to : `return render(request, 'jinja2/index.html', {'json_dict': json_dict})`

Comment: @Loïc I tried ur codes, but same error happens.What do you think of other problems?

Comment: @Loïc I updated my question.if u know something please help me

Comment: This is another question. You should open a new "ticket" and update your code.